# Where do I best ask my question about PayPal's prerequisites and obligations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I have a question about PayPal and what just striked me, is that if it wouldn't be PayPal, where would I ask questions about websites and web-services? **On "WebApps" it is not allowed**, because there I am only allowed to ask about websites that "behave like applications"?

So as I assume I cannot ask on "Webapps"(.stackexchange.com), how about "Personal Finance and Money"?
Sounds good to me, but: I basically want to open either a "Premier" (individual who sells) or "Business" (merchant) account with PayPal, so my questions are actually all about that, about the prerequisites, fee structure, obligations etc.

So that is not exactly "personal finance" anymore and very specifically tailored to PayPal. If you look at this case, where on Stack Exchange would you ask?

Comment: Give a concrete example question otherwise you're just making it vague for no reason

Comment: Bear in mind that there isn't (yet?) a stackexchange site for every subject known to humanity, so it might be that the answer is 'not at stackexchange'...

Comment: AakashM I am totally aware of that and agree with you. If that is the opinion of you or someone else, you can reply and look if it gets upvoted. Dear random, I think it is already specific enough, you may read my text again. I could've just written "PayPal" and done...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this part:

> about the prerequisites, fee structure, obligations etc

of your questions, I would say there isn't a StackExchange that can help you. These type questions would be better answered by PayPal, and their relevant support forums as it is related to their business model and how their system works.

Comment: +1, because if you take a 3rd party's advice and are wrong, PayPal will keep all your cash.  They've done it before.  Don't risk it.

Comment: Won't, that is a really good point! I don't fear that so much yet, but of course there can still be a lot of fees burdened upon on by PayPal. I will keep it simple and contact them personally with all my questions, while continuing to google.

Answer (score 2):

> I basically want to open either a "Premier" (individual who sells) or "Business" (merchant) account with PayPal, so my questions are actually all about that

This isn't really enough to go on, but http://answers.onstartups.com *might* be appropriate. More detail of your actual desired question would help.

Comment: That is a good idea, I always forget about them. I upvote your answer, because I couldn't find a question about PayPal here yet, so future readers probably will appreciate your advice.